# Regexp & back references

Tags: .net, regex

Guys
I need help to extract from string

"AAA, BBB", "CCC", DDDD

following groups:

1. AAA, BBB
2. CCC
3. DDDD

Is possible extract three groups by regex and if yes then how?

Thanks.

Comment: Will those quotes always be there in that order?

Comment: in what programming language/tool?

Comment: Is there supposed to be some quotes before the DDDD?

Comment: 2BoltClock: Rule is simple. Words separated by comma and they can be in quotas if term contains more then one word. But term can contains quotas, for instance: toys 'r' us.

Comment: Do you really need regular expressions? Wouldn't `String.Split(",")` be enough?

Comment: 2Hosam Aly: No. If I will use String.Split(",") then I will have following groups: 
1. "AAA
2. BBB" 
3. "CCC"
4. DDDD 

but #1 and #2 should be togather.

Comment: So this is CSV? I would recommend a specific CSV parser, such as http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: A handy tool for testing regular expressions can be downloaded from http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
public void RunTest()
{
    const string toTest = "\"AAA, BBB\", \"CCC\", \"DDDD\"";
    var exp = new Regex("\G(?:^|,)\s*\"([^\"])\"");
    var matches = exp.Matches(toTest);
    foreach (var match in matches.Cast())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Matched expression: {0}", match);
        foreach (var group in match.Groups.Cast())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Matched group: {0}", group);
        }
    }
}
```

will return

```
Matched expression: "AAA, BBB"
Matched group: "AAA, BBB"
Matched group: AAA, BBB
Matched expression: , "CCC"
Matched group: , "CCC"
Matched group: CCC
Matched expression: , "DDDD"
Matched group: , "DDDD"
Matched group: DDDD
```

so collecting every second group you get what I suppose you wanted.
Note that I added double quotes around your DDDD. I thought that was a typo.
If its not a typo you can try the regular expression:

```
var exp = new Regex("\G(?:^|,)(?:\s(?:\"([^\"])\")|([^\",]))");
```

Explanations:

```
\G The match must occur at the point where the previous match ended.
[^"] Any character except the double quote
\s Any whitespace
* zero or more occurrences of the preceding element
( and ) define a group
(?: defines a noncapturing group
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`var delimiterPattern = @",(?=(?:[^\"]\"[^\"]\")(?![^\"]\"))";
var parts = string.Split(delimiterPattern);`

for string: toys "r" us", "AAAA", "toys "r" us","toys ,r,","toys ,"r",",test

will return:
1. "toys "r" us"
2.  "AAAA"
3.  "toys "r" us"
4. "toys ,r,"
5. "toys ,"r","
6. test